# 2-pass filter in Wireshark/tshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark

The option **-Y**, **-2** and **-R** in `tshark` confuse me a long time.

After I read the manual, I know that **-Y** is used in single-pass filter and **-2** in 2-pass filter (in case where we can not get some info until 1st pass filter is over)

But I still can not understand what is the difference between `-2 -Y 'blabla'` and `-2 -R 'balabala'` and `-2 -Y 'blalal' -R 'blala'`

And I also did an experiment that drive me crazy:

```
tshark -n -r test.pcap -2 -R 'frame.number > 0'
  1   0.000000 10.140.28.17 -> 10.74.68.58  TCP 80 62276 > 8989 [SYN, ECN, CWR] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32 TSval=330325315 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
  2   0.000056  10.74.68.58 -> 10.140.28.17 TCP 76 8989 > 62276 [SYN, ACK, ECN] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2078759468 TSecr=330325315 WS=128
  3   0.000678 10.140.28.17 -> 10.74.68.58  TCP 68 62276 > 8989 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131744 Len=0 TSval=330325316 TSecr=2078759468
  4   0.000756 10.140.28.17 -> 10.74.68.58  HTTP 158 GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
  5   0.000770  10.74.68.58 -> 10.140.28.17 TCP 68 8989 > 62276 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=91 Win=29056 Len=0 TSval=2078759468 TSecr=330325316
```

But when I execute `tshark -n -r test.pcap -2 -R 'frame.number > 1'`, there is nothing printed. How to explain this?

My tshark version is: TShark 1.10.6 (v1.10.6 from master-1.10)

Can you help me with this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I answered this question on [http://ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/58343/2-pass-filter-in-wiresharktshark), but I'll paste my answer here as well in case anyone looks here for an answer instead of there.

`-R` specifies a *read* filter, so only matching packets from a file are read and processed; unmatched packets are essentially treated as if the file didn't contain them at all. Contrast this with `-Y`, which specifies a *display* filter, so only matching packets are displayed, but all packets are still read and processed.

The problem you're seeing with `frame.number` is a known bug that was determined not worth fixing long ago. See [Bug 380](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=380), *"wireshark -R doesn't support 'frame.number' as a read filter "*.

You can also follow along some of the history behind `-R` vs. `-Y` here:

- [Bug 8223](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8223)
- [Bug 8316](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8316)
- [Bug 8529](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8529)
- [Bug 9048](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9048)
- Wireshark-dev mailing list discussion:

  - [Wireshark's Local archive](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201303/msg00008.html)
  - [MARC archives](https://marc.info/?l=wireshark-dev&m=136220351121519)
  - [The Mail Archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/wireshark-dev@wireshark.org/msg27170.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the links to bug reports and mailing list discussions -- it's great to see well-documented answers like this one.