# Wireshark tshark -R vs -Y filter option

Tags: wireshark, tshark

tshark provides `-R` and `-Y` filters, what is the difference between read filter `-R` and display filter `-Y`. I have been using the `-Y` option to apply a filter to get a subset of the logs while converting them to pdml (xml) for further processing.

```
tshark -r source.pcap -Y "(s1ap.procedureCode == 13 && nas_eps.nas_msg_emm_type == 0x5e )" -T pdml > filtered_xml.xml
```

This works fine on windows build. However -Y is an invalid option on linux build.

```
mymachine{66}$ tshark -v
TShark 1.8.10 (SVN Rev Unknown from unknown)
```

- what is the difference between the `-Y` and `-R` filter options ?
- In the linux build I do not see the `-Y` option, what is the equivalent that can be used ?

From `tshark -h` on windows

```
-R <read filter>         packet Read filter in Wireshark display filter syntax

-Y <display filter>      packet displaY filter in Wireshark display filter
```

Comment: Note that `-R` option is much much more faster than `-Y`. Also `-R` without `-2` is deprecated. So you have to use `-2R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has come up recently, so you might want to read my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339807/2-pass-filter-in-wireshark-tshark) question.  The `-Y` option was not available until [Wireshark 1.10.0](https://www.wireshark.org/news/20130605.html), so if you want to be able to use `-Y`, you will need to upgrade your version of Wireshark on your Linux platform.